# How to print all digits of a large number in python?

Tags: python, numbers

So, I have a very large number that I'm working out in python, but when I try to print it I get something like this:

```
3.101541146879488e+80
```

How do I print all the digits of my lovely number?

Comment: how is the data created? Have a look at the [decimal madule](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)

Comment: Have you read about [string formatting in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)? How do you know there are more digits?

Comment: is `long(x)` okay for this?

Comment: If this is a real number and not a Decimal, only about 15 or 16 of those digits are going to be accurate anyway.

Comment: @C.B. Python has had unlimited size longs for a while now.

Answer (score 13):

both `int` and `long` work for this

```
>>> a
3.101541146879488e+80
>>> int(a)
310154114687948792274813492416458874069290879741385354066259033875756607541870592L
>>> long(a)
310154114687948792274813492416458874069290879741385354066259033875756607541870592L
>>> print (int(a))
310154114687948792274813492416458874069290879741385354066259033875756607541870592
>>> print (long(a))
310154114687948792274813492416458874069290879741385354066259033875756607541870592
```

Comment: Note that if `a` is a float most of those digits are simply an artefact of the way it is stored at IEEE-754 double precision

Comment: Yea but what about a number that has 10000 digits?